# How do I store Point datatype in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server

How do I best store a `Point` data type in my SQL Server database?

I was thinking of just making it `nvarchar`, then inserting a point-string like: `100,246` then just splitting the string when I read the value from the DB but is there a way to just insert as a `Point`?

Comment: Do you mean Point as in x,y coordinates?

Comment: @Katstevens yah, I do.

Comment: Serialization out of the question?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Oh, I never thought of that. :) Not out of the question at all.

Comment: Please **do not** stick two elements into a single column - it violates the **first normal form** of database design - one column, **one value**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server did support `Point` datatype:

- [Point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964737.aspx)

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PointTest]
(
    [RowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MyPoint] [GEOMETRY] NOT NULL,
)
```

Insert (SRID = 4326):

```
INSERT INTO PointTest(MyPoint) values (GEOMETRY::Point(3, -4, 4326))
```

Select:

```
SELECT MyPoint.STX X, MyPoint.STY Y FROM PointTest;
```

SQLFiddle: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d1d6/12)

For more information on Spatial Data Types:

- [Spatial Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can define 2 int variable for each dimension. in this way there is no need to split the value you read from DB.

```
X int,
Y int
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Geographical points, then maybe look at the [geography](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) data type for a "round-earth coordinate system" or the [geometry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx) data type for a "Euclidean (flat) coordinate system."

The [spatial data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx) capabilities of SQL Server since around 2008 can help with various methods for interrogating spatial data including (but not limited to) [point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964737.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For geography points:

```
create table foo (
  id int primary key,
  latlon [GEOGRAPHY]
);

insert into foo values (1, geography::Point(40.7, -74, 4326));

select 
  latlon.Lat as latitude,
  latlon.Long as longitude,
  latlon.ToString() as plaintext
from foo;
```